# Retrieve database messages (e.g., "Print" statement outputs but not error messages) in ADO

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, ado

I use ASP 3.0 on IIS 7 and SQL Server 2008 as my dbms.
I have a stored procedure coded in SQL Server. I have some "Print" statements in it and also a select statement that throws out a recordset after the procedure is executed.
I can retrieve the recordset by using

> Set recordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
>
> recordSet.Open "Execute my_procedure", dbConn

What I wish to do here is to retrieve the outputs of the "Print" statements that I am executing in the stored procedure.
Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ADO, the output from `PRINT` statements is populated in the [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675299%28VS.85%29.aspx) collection, so you simply have to loop through that collection:

```
Dim e
For Each e In dbConn.Errors
    Response.Write e.Description
Next
```

Comment: This does not work when I use the ODBC driver (`DRIVER={SQL Server}`).

Comment: It also does not work when you use the OLEDB driver. So it's safe to say it does not work at all, and is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the SqlInfoMessage event to trap the print statement from the connection object.

```
SQLConnection.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) 
{                                    
   string printresponse = e.Message;                                    
};
```

You can get much more details from this link,
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=344

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question is about classic ASP, not ASP.NET.